# How to extract the integer part age from a varchar age column

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL Server table, I have an `age` column which has values like `62-year old`, `35-year old`, `2 -year old` and `ABCD`.

I want to create a new age column where if AGE is 65 and over. Group them to 65yrs old and older AND if AGE is under 65 then 'Under 65yrs old'

I tried using substring function like this

```
SUBSTRING(TRIM(' 62-year old  '), 1, 2)
```

The problem is that there are some ages in 1 digit like 8-year old where it fails with an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2-' to data type int

This is my CASE condition

```
 SELECT
     (CASE 
          WHEN SUBSTRING(TRIM('- ' from age), 1, 2) >= 65  
              THEN '65 Years Old and older' 
              ELSE 'Under 65 Years Old'
      END) age_group 
FROM
    table
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Why would you even have this? An age is a number - if you store a number and derive the text for presentation separately, you have no issues.

Comment: I can ot agree more thay you need to fix your design. Otherwise you also have problems like an 8 year old is "older" than a 62 year old.

Comment: That age changes every your. Wouldn't it be better to store a birth year (as integer, of course)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a current version of SQL Server (you haven't tagged any specific version), a quick way to just extract the integers from a text string would be to use *translate*, such as:

```
declare @MyBadData varchar(50) = 'Under 65 years old';
select Trim(Translate(@MyBadData, ' ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-', Space(28)));
```

Comment: getting this error Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '62         
' to data type int.

Comment: Can you amend [this Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=723cca34e2e45705740ca720c49ac98d) to demonstrate?

Comment: done, can u check

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ccf456ff89f21f19de2cba8c3325426d

Comment: No, @Tushaar, I meant can you modify the working fiddle with sample data that reproduces your error, your fiddle just reports the obivous missing object error.

Comment: very strange since it works in fiddle but giving me error in SQL Server 2020 version inside my machine... https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fc055075e45908eecf16b0def9d8166b

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to help unless you can reproduce the error - and SQL Server 2020 is not a thing - there's SQL Server 2019 or 2022 (in preview only)

Comment: Your solution will works only if the collation is CI AI... Just ADD a COLLATE clause with the right collation and it will be better !

Answer (score 0):

If all numbers are replaced by '' then the result is a group of characters and if these characters are replaced by '' then the result is a number. For multiple numbers, split the string by a nonnumerical character, [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f94cd01cc3f6d9ee071ff0985c4ef743) :

```sql
select *
from(values(' 62-year old  ')) as t(age)
cross apply (values(replace(translate(t.age, '234567890', '111111111'), '1', ''))) as c(c)
cross apply (values(replace(translate(t.age, c.c, replicate('a', len(c.c+'.')-1)), 'a', ''))) as n(n);

select *
from(values(' 62-year old and-70 year old')) as t(age)
cross apply (values(replace(translate(t.age, '234567890', '111111111'), '1', ''))) as c(c)
cross apply (
select value
from string_split(translate(t.age, c.c, replicate('a', len(c.c+'.')-1)), 'a') as s
where s.value <> ''
) as n;
```